# ios : Integrate both BrainTree SDK and Paypal SDK in one app

Tags: ios, xcode, paypal, braintree

I am trying to integrate both braintree and paypal(third party lib) in my application. I user cocoapods to integrate braintree (ver 4.x)[third paty lib] and manual integration for paypal, but when I compile the code I see

```
91 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

I tried integrating these library individually in different project and they are working fine if I integrate them in one project I get this error.
So basically its the case where two 3rd party libraries are conflicting, please help me out to resolve this

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: Looks like this is being handled in [Github](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/387)

Comment: @Jerry can you please elaborate I mean I am using pods to integrate them and I need to keep both of them in my project and enable one of them as per the configuration